# What's wrong with my Meyer Lemon Tree?

Tags: leaves, citrus, lemons

My young meyer lemon tree's are getting these yellowish spots and then falling off. Despite this, it has still bloomed and has quite a bit new growth. What is wrong?[image: meyer lemon tree leaves]

[image: fallen meyer lemon leaf close up]

[image: meyer lemon tree leaves 2]

Comment: That looks like chlorosis.  Do you use any fertilizer, or soil amendments?